# text won't go in DIV

Tags: css, html, button, navbar

I'm new to CSS and this is my first button i'm ever making, I'm having trouble putting the text into the button. Well, It's IN the button however it's not aligned right. I don't know how to fix this but here's my code

```
     body {
   font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
   background-color: #DB1F1F;
  }

  .navbar-menu {
     margin: auto;
     height: 100px;
     width: 95px;
     background-color: green;
     padding: 10px 40px;
     font-size: 25px;
}

  .navbar-menu:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

I don't know what's wrong with it so can someone help?

oh and: HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
   <title>Button</title>
    </head>
<body>
   <center>
     <div class="navbar-menu">HTML/CSS</div>
    </center>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of what you are doing with your html as well?

Comment: Please post JS fiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PkDKA/

Comment: how would you like it to align?

Comment: kind of at the center of the button

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/VHHJq/1/

Comment: Is this what you want? [http://jsfiddle.net/KNM6F/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/KNM6F/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you are using as your button elements (divs, spans, lis), you can use:

```
//use for any element type
text-align: center;

//use only for inline element types e.g. span
vertical-align: middle;

//use for any block element type e.g. div 
//(replace 90 with height of block element)
line-height: 90px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <style type="text/css">
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background-color: #DB1F1F;
}
.navbar-menu {
 background-color: green;
    font-size: 25px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 43px;
    width: 150px;
}
.navbar-menu:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
</style>
 <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
 <title>Button</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="navbar-menu"><center>
HTML/CSS
</center></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That aligns it to the left, The text needs to be at the center of the button though